# xquery - function tokenize for regular expression

Tags: xml, regex, xquery, tokenize

I have modified my code with regular expression but I have problems with `fn:tokenize`. This is a bit part of my xml file:

```
<radix>
...
<EV>
  <accoppiamenti>
     <accoppiamento specie="e01" />
  </accoppiamenti>
</EV>
  <accoppiamenti>
     <accoppiamento specie="e00" />
     <accoppiamento specie="e01" />
     <accoppiamento specie="e02" />
  </accoppiamenti>
</EV>
...
</radix>
```

This is the part of my file xquery with tokenize:

```
for $ev in $snapshot/EV
let $stringa := $ev/accoppiamenti//accoppiamento/@specie
return(
    fn:tokenize($stringa,"e")        
)
```

The expected output is `01 00 01 02` but the effective output is `0100` (without space).
What's the trouble? Thanks at all for the helps.

Comment: which xquery processor? I think this shouldn't even work because fn:tokenize(..) expects a single entry as the first parameter and you're giving it a sequence (in the second 'accoppiamenti').

Comment: I use ExistDB. But if I print $stringa (with data($stringa) ), it print the correct value: `01000102`

Comment: @EwoutGraswinckel Can I do a casting of $stringa to make it work for fn:tokenize?

Comment: Have you tried fn:tokenize(string-join($stringa),"e") ? 
I'm not really sure what you want to achieve though. If there is always an e in front then it's even overkill to use tokenize, you can just loop over specie attributes and remove the e.

Comment: @EwoutGraswinckel I solved! I mustn't use tokenize, simply I use `$stringa[1]` for e01, `$stringa[2]` for e00 etc. Now I must cycle from the element $string[4] to the element $string[last()-3]. How can I do? Is there a cycle `for` in C style?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but I'm also pretty that you're trying to work against the 'xquery way' of doing things. Why do you now suddenly want to things in reverse order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokenize can be useful, but needs to be applied to single values at a time. Not sure why eXistDB is appears to be casting things to number before output. In your case, you don't really need tokenize. The older character-by-character replacement function `fn:translate()` will do too. And if you want make sure results are space-separated, try wrapping the for in a `fn:string-join()`:

```
fn:string-join(
  for $a in $snapshot/EV/accoppiamenti//accoppiamento/@specie
  return
    fn:translate($a,"e", ""),
" ")
```

If you want to reverse order of things, just wrap the for in `fn:reverse()`, before you string-join everything. You can nest for loops if you want to iterate over specie attributes within each EV separately..

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to `fn:tokenize(...)` (although @grtjn's answer will probably be more efficient), you need to apply the function to every single element, for example in a node step:

```
for $ev in $snapshot/EV
return $ev/accoppiamenti//accoppiamento/fn:tokenize(@specie,"e")
```